# How to get the average number of a set of observations in R

Tags: r

I have part of a dataset like this:

```
numero  direccion
 5      Up
 5      Up
-10     Down
 0      Down
 0      Down
-5      Down
 20     Up
 10     Up
 5      Up
 0      Down
 0      Down
-5      Down
```

I need the average of a certain position given by the variable 'direccion'. For example, the average of 'Up' would be:

```
(5+5)+(20+10+5)/2 = 22.5
```

which takes the observation 'numero' and gets the average given the number of times the variable 'direccion' equals 'Up' in a single vector.

I hope this is clear enough for you to understand.

Comment: *"gets the average given the number of times the variable 'direccion' equals 'Up' in a single vector"*: what does that mean? Do you just want the average per group?

Comment: `(5+5)+(20+10+5)/2 = 27.5`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how `(5+5)+(20+10+5)/2 = 22.5` is averaging but I think this is what you actually want to do.

```
aggregate(DF$numero,list(DF$direccion),mean)
```